# Color merge problem upon drawing ellipses above lines in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, drawing, qpainter

I'm developing a small painter-like application. I'd like my application to have a feature which would allow user to draw points and then connect them with lines in the order in which the points were drawn. I also want my points to be drawn above the lines. Here's how i'm trying to achieve this:

```
 void ImageViewer::on_linesAct_triggered()
{
    QPainter paint(objectpix);
    QPen LinePen (QColor(255-pointcolor[currentset-1].red(),255-pointcolor[currentset-1].green(),255-pointcolor[currentset-1].blue()));
    LinePen.setWidth(5);

    for(int i=0;i<count[currentset-1]-1;i++)
    {
        paint.setPen(LinePen);
        QPoint p1(static_cast<int>(round(tableX[i][currentset-1])),static_cast<int>(round(tableY[i][currentset-1])));
        QPoint p2(static_cast<int>(round(tableX[i+1][currentset-1])), static_cast<int>(round(tableY[i+1][currentset-1])));
        paint.drawLine(p1,p2);
        paint.setPen(QPen(pointcolor[currentset-1]));
        paint.setBrush(QBrush(pointcolor[currentset-1],Qt::SolidPattern));
        paint.drawEllipse(p1,2,2);
        paint.drawEllipse(p2,2,2);
    }

    /...
}
```

It works as intended except the fact that colors of lines and points kinda merge(not sure on nomenclature) together. The picture down below llustrates the problem.
[image]
Any idea on possible solution?

Comment: I can not repeat the problem and I think your code is incomplete because you have `LinePen.setWidth(5)` and `paint.drawEllipse(p1,2,2)`, so why your ellipses bigger than line? I suggest you draw ellipses 2 times: 1 bigger ellipse bellow and 1 above.

Comment: @Serhiy Kulish you are right, ellipses i used to draw above old ones were too smal to cover old ones. I changed the width of pen and it solved my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider the list of points [A, B, C, D] and your code:

- Iteration 1: p1 = A, p2 = B

  - Draw line between A and B
  - Draw ellipse at A and B
- Iteration 2: p1 = B, p2 = C

  - Draw line between B and C <-- Will draw above the ellipse at B
  - Draw ellipse at B and C <-- Will re-draw the ellipse at B
- Iteration 3: p1 = C, p2 = D

  - Draw line between C and D <-- Will draw above the ellipse at C
  - Draw ellipse at C and D <-- Will re-draw the ellipse at C

You are drawing your ellipses twice with a the start of line between them. What you can see is the artifacts due to the aliasing (as mentionned in the other answer) and the first ellipse drawn below the second line.

The easiest way to achieve that is to use two loops:

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
public:
    MyWidget(): QWidget()
    {}
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent* ev) override
    {
        QVector<QPoint> pointcolor;
        pointcolor << QPoint(10, 12) << QPoint(40, 60) << QPoint(70, 20) << QPoint(100, 100);
        QPainter paint(this);
        paint.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
        QPen LinePen (Qt::red);
        LinePen.setWidth(5);

        for(int i = 1;i != pointcolor.length();++i)
        {
            paint.setPen(LinePen);
            QPoint p1 = pointcolor.at(i - 1);
            QPoint p2 = pointcolor.at(i);
            paint.drawLine(p1,p2);
        }

        // Draw the points above the lines
        paint.setPen(Qt::green);
        paint.setBrush(Qt::green);
        for(QPoint const& point: pointcolor)
        {
            paint.drawEllipse(point,2,2);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: I solved my problem with help of @Serhiy Kulish, but i'll mark your post as an answer, it might be useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could try to set a [rendering hint](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpainter.html#RenderHint-enum) to the painter, using `QPainter::setRenderHint`, something like:

```
QPainter paint(objectpix);
paint.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
```